# Angular js modular approach controller structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found [this post](http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript) about structuring angular applications and it's really great . I'm planning on structuring my angular app based on the aforementioned. Now, if we try to view the code on the post:

```
var userModule = angular.module('userModule',[]);

userModule.factory('userService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return new UserService($http);
}]);

userModule.factory('userModel', ['userService', function(userService) {
  return new UserModel(userService);
}]);

userModule.controller('loginController', ['$scope', 'userModel', LoginController]);

userModule.controller('registrationController', ['$scope', 'userModel', RegistrationController]);
```

I was wondering what would the `LoginController` code might look like? Also based on the post, you will create for example a `LoginModule.js` file and place it along the related js files. Now the question is: Is the `LoginController.js` file included automatically or there will be a configuration or code requirement somewhere?

This inquiry will not be limited to controllers alone, maybe there are also ways of doing so with services, filters and directives. What do you think?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly your question is about the structure of angularJS scripts without polluting the global scope?

Comment: Yes. And the real intention is to established modular structure with the js files. It's like saying each controllers, services, filters and directives will have their own file. Did I make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the structure from the article, this is how I structure my angular apps.

In this case we have four main modules (folders): `cart`, `common`, `product` and `user`. Every main folder can have subfolder for modules, controllers, services, directives, etc. I will focus on product folder.

```
|-- product/
|   |-- modules/
|   |   |--  Product.js
|   |   |--  Search.js
|   |-- controllers/    
|   |   |-- search/
|   |   |   |-- SearchResultsController.js
|   |   |-- product/
|   |   |   |-- ProductDetailController.js
|   |-- services/
|   |   |-- search/
|   |   |   |-- SearchResultsModel.js
|   |   |-- product/
|   |   |   |-- ProductModel.js
|   |   |   |-- ProductService.js
|   |-- directives/
|   |   |   |-- ProductDirective.js
|   |   |   |-- OtherDirective.js
```

Each main folder has to have main angularJS module, where it registers other stuff. In case of product it's `product/modules/Product.js` This module can then be included to use the whole structure in your application.

In the main module for product you can register other submodules for subfolders like controllers, services, directives etc. In case of product module there are `product.controllers`, `product.services` and `product.directives` submodules. It also registers the search module, which can have it's own submodules for search controllers, directives... for better separation. The code for the main `product` module then looks like this:

```
angular.module('product.controllers', []);
angular.module('product.services', []);
angular.module('product.directives', []);

angular.module('product', ['product.controllers', 'product.services', 'product.directives', 'search'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    ...

}]);
```

On the submodules for controllers, directives etc. you then register other stuff of your application. `ProductService.js` for example looks like this:

```
angular.module('product.services').factory('productSerivice', [function(){

    ...

}]);
```

And `SearchResultsController.js` migth look like this:

```
angular.module('search.controllers').controller('SearchResultsController', ['$scope', 
    function($scope){

    ...

}]);
```

This allows you to have each entity, be it a controller, service or directive, in a separate file without polluting the global scope. Also it's separated and structured to modules and can be easily added or removed from the whole application.